# onChange event is only occurring once when state is managed by redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, onchange, react-redux-form

I am fetching an array with single object from **redux** store.

`this.props.license :[0: {id: 24, domain: "xyz.com", app_url: "https...", purchase_code: "395"}]`

And then creating a form to update the value in the react form.

But when trying to change the value the `onChange` event is only occurring once.

I am managing a new state in the react component to save the changes that I am doing on `onChange` event.

Is this a correct way in which I am coding?

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../../store/actions/index';
import Spinner from '../../components/Spinner/Spinner';

const DATABASE_LABELS={
    id:'ID',
    domain:'Domain',
    app_url:'APP URL',
    purchase_code:'Purchase Code',

}

class editLicense extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            editLicense:{}
        }
    }
    onChangeHandler=(event, type)=>{

        // [event.target.name]=[event.target.value]
        let newLicense={...this.state.editLicense}
        newLicense[type]=event.target.value
        console.log(newLicense)
         console.log('before',this.state.editLicense)

        this.setState({
            editLicense :{
                ...this.state.editLicense,
                [event.target.name]:event.target.value
            }
        })
        console.log(this.state.editLicense)
    }

    componentDidMount=()=>{  
        this.props.viewLicenceDetails(this.props.token, this.props.match.params.id)
        this.setState({
            editLicense:this.props.licenses[0]
        })
        console.log(this.state.editLicense)
    }
    render(){
        let formdata=<Spinner/>;
        if(!this.props.loading){
            let license=Object.keys(this.props.licenses[0])
            .map(key=>{
                return [
                    key,
                    this.props.licenses[0][key]
                ]
            })
            let form=license.map((p, index)=>{
                return(
                <div className="form-group" key={p[0]}>
                    <label htmlFor={p[0]}> {DATABASE_LABELS[p[0]]} </label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" 
                            id={p[0]} 
                            value={p[1]} 
                            name={p[0]}
                            onChange={(event) => this.onChangeHandler(event, p[0])} />
                </div>)
            })

            formdata=(
                <form>
                    {form}
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            )
        }
        return(
            <div className="container">
                {formdata}
            </div>
    )}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
    return({
        token:state.auth.idToken,
        licenses:state.license.licenses,
        loading:state.license.loading,
        err:state.license.error
    })
 }

 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch=>{
    return({
         updateLicenseData:(token, type, newVal)=>dispatch(actionCreators.updateLicense(token, type, newVal)),
         viewLicenceDetails:(token, id)=>dispatch(actionCreators.fetchOneLicense(token, id))

 })
 }
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(editLicense);
```

Comment: where do you use `this.state.editLicense` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question title is a little misleading.  Currently, your state is not fully managed by Redux, but only initially fetched from the Redux state.

You are currently:

1. Fetching the Redux state (via props), and copying it to your component state in `componentDidMount`.
2. Populating your input's `value` from the props (from the Redux state).
3. Updating your local component state via `onChange` -> `onChangeHandler`.

(2) is your problem currently.  Your props are not currently being changed (since you're not calling any Redux actions), so the value of your `input` element is never changing.  Its a little unintuitive, but this results in changes only being detected once.

You need to populate your input `value` prop using your state.  In your `render()` function, try replacing instances of `this.props.licenses[0]` with `this.state.editLicense`:

```js
    if(!this.props.loading){
        let license=Object.keys(this.state.editLicense)
        .map(key=>{
            return [
                key,
                this.state.editLicense[key]
            ]
        })
        ...
    }
```

This way, when your state is updated, the 'current' value of the form will be updated on re-render, and the `input` component will be fully controlled.

As a side note:

```js
this.setState({
    editLicense:this.props.licenses[0]
})
console.log(this.state.editLicense)
```

This is not guaranteed to work.  `setState` should typically be considered asynchronous.  If you want to do something in response to an updated state outside of the render cycle, you should provide a callback to `setState`:

```js
this.setState({
        editLicense:this.props.licenses[0]
    },
    () => console.log(this.state.editLicense)
);
```

Comment: Thank you Dylan Walker! :) Your solution worked fine. I have one question regarding "Fetching the Redux state (via props), and copying it to your component state in componentDidMount." . Is this a correct approach to update component state from fetched redux state?

Comment: @RitaBala It depends on your intended pattern a little bit.  If you simply want to set your initial state from your Redux state, make a bunch of intermediate changes (such as editing your form), then 'submit' the updated state later via a Redux action, then your approach is fine.

However, if you expect something else to edit your Redux state and want your form to be updated to reflect that in the same lifecycle, I'd avoid using component state at all, and strictly use Redux state.